# Google Apps Script Document Template Permissions Issue

Tags: google-apps-script

I added a Doc that has a bunch of custom onOpen() scripts to the template library, when I select the document template and create a new document the scripts no longer work. It seems to be some kind of permissions issue because when I go to edit the script within the new document I'm asked to Allow permission, I select allow, and then the script starts working. I need the permission to be granted by default!

Comment: I have reviewed it, thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I need the permission to be granted by default!

This is unfortunately not possible :( Please refer [Container-bound Scripts > Access to bound scripts](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/bound#access_to_bound_scripts).

As it indicates -

- Only users who have permission to edit a container can run its bound
  script. Collaborators who have only view access cannot open the
  script editor, although if they make a copy of the parent file, they
  become the owner of the copy and will be able to see and run a copy
  of the script.

As a solution perhaps, "...you can force the authorization dialog..." as indicated at [Manual authorization scopes for Sheets, Docs, Slides, and Forms](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/authorization#manual_authorization_scopes_for_sheets_docs_slides_and_forms).

Hope this helps!